# How to avoid stringify and parse data while storing in ioredis

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, ioredis

We use ioredis to store api responses in redis cache.
Since, redis does not allow objects to be stored, i am stringifying the [typical response object](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema) and parsing it whenever required.

There are some apis whose response contains arrays of 25000 objects

Sometimes, whenever there is heavy load on the server and such apis are being called, js heap goes out of memory while parsing the response.

Is there anyway in redis by which i can avoid stringying and parsing the response

Comment: Stringifying and parsing the content isn't the problem; weight of data is. I'd strongly suggest that you re-evaluate your solution as needing to store an array of 25,000 objects in a single entity is, frankly, ridiculous. Without knowing the use case then this question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan   Still, even if we exclude those response with large data, i often get heap out of memory due to heavy load. I have tried to reduce the response object data as much as possible and have seen significant imprvements in memory usage. But still, i was just curious how can we just avoid parsing and stringifying.

Comment: Do you need to only query a portion of these documents? If so, you might be able to use [RedisJSON](https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/) to store it. That would allow you to store an object instead and then just query the bits you care about.